# Airflow 1.10.10 Schedule change for DAG

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow 1.10.10 and wanted to know how to change a Aiflow DAG schedule . I checked online and in most of the comments its suggested that to change schedule of a DAG, create a new DAG with new dag_id, or change dag_id of existing DAG and give new schedule_interval . Attempt to change schedule of a existing DAG will not work in straight forward manner and will throw error or might create scheduling error.

However I tried to test this so that I can create the scenario where my DAG schedule change leads to erroneous cases . This I tried by only change schedule_interval in DAG file. I tried below change of schedule in my DAG and all worked as expected. Schedule was changed properly and no erroneous case was found .

- Started with @Daily
- Changed to 10 min
- Changed to 17 min
- Changed to 15 min
- Changed to 5 min

Can someone please clarify what kind of problem may arise if we change the schedule_interval in a DAG without changing ID.

Comment: I think the main issue is when you try to do a backfill after you've changed the schedule after a few uns

Comment: @SimonDarr can you please share any discrepancies you might have faced when you have changed the schedule of a DAG without changing dag_id. I use catchup=False to prevent backfill so backfill runs are not an issue for me. But I am wondering beside that can any other issue occur due to change in schedule_interval of a DAG.

Comment: You should be okay if you don't backfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see this recommendation on the old Airflow Confluence page on [Common Pitfalls](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614).

> When needing to change your start_date and schedule interval, change the name of the dag (a.k.a. dag_id) - I follow the convention : my_dag_v1, my_dag_v2, my_dag_v3, my_dag_v4, etc...
>
> - Changing schedule interval always requires changing the dag_id, because previously run TaskInstances will not align with the new schedule interval
> - Changing start_date without changing schedule_interval is safe, but changing to
>   an earlier start_date will not create any new DagRuns for the time
>   between the new start_date and the old one, so tasks will not
>   automatically backfill to the new dates.  If you manually create
>   DagRuns, tasks will be scheduled, as long as the DagRun date is after
>   both the task start_date and the dag start_date.

I don't know the author's intent but I imagine changing the schedule_interval can cause confusion for users. When they revisit these task, they will wonder why the current schedule_interval does not match past task executions because that information is not stored at the task level.

Changing the schedule_interval does not impact past dagruns or tasks. The change will affect when new dagruns are created, which impacts the tasks within those dagruns.

I personally do not modify the dag_id when I update a DAG's scheduler_interval for two reasons.

1. If I keep the previous DAG, I am unnecessarily inducing more stress on the scheduler for processing a DAG that will not be turned on.
2. If I do not keep the previous DAG, I essentially lose all the history of the dagrun where it had a different schedule_interval.

Edit: Looks like there is an [Github Issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10180) created to move the Common Pitfall page but it is stale.

Comment: thanks for your response . So from what i understand from this is that changing schedule_interval of a DAG might create confusion for users as the scheduled runs will be for different timestamp. But can you also share some light on below.
1)Can you please elaborate what you mean by "The change will affect when new dagruns are created, which impacts the tasks within those dagruns". What is the impact you are referring to here . 
2)And did you happen to observer any issue if you only change schedule_interval for a DAG without changing DAG id.

Comment: 1) The change referred to is the execution_date. The execution_date depends on the scheduler_interval.

 2) I have not observed any issues when changing only the scheduler_interval aside from the potential confusions mentioned above. I have used 1.8.1 to 2.0.0 and have been able to change the schedule_interval without breaking my DAGs.

Comment: @AlanMa I tried updating the schedule_interval and am able to see it updated in the "schedule" column in the UI but the "Next Run" column is still calculated off the previous schedule_interval. Were you seeing similar behaviour?